# Java int zero prefix?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

Hi.

How does Java deal with bytes, ints, shorts and longs prefixed by zeroes, e.g.

```
// Prints 8.
System.out.println(010);

// Prints 64.
System.out.println(0100);
```

So, *8^(n-1)*, I guess. But why?

Explanations are appreciated!

**EDIT:**
So that's how it works. However, nobody knows why, it seems, and the other topic is dead.. Gn people. :)

Comment: A lot of us want to know *why* Java borrowed this from C.  I don't think we're ever going to get a satisfactory answer. :-)

Comment: See [Octal number literals: when? why? ever?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569/octal-number-literals-when-why-ever) for discussion about the *why* behind this question.

Answer (score 3):

A zero prefix is interpreted as an octal number.

10 in octal is 8 in decimal; 100 in octal is 64 in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Search for 'octal' on this page: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: *The prefix 0 indicates octal, whereas 0x indicates hexadecimal.* Hex values are often prefixed with 0x; I see that all the time, but why are octal numbers prefixed with 0?