# Javascript alert number starting with 0

Tags: javascript

I have a button where in the code behind I add a `onclick` and I pass a unique ID which will be passed to the js function. The id starts with a 0.

It wasn't working and eventually I figured out that the number, id, it was passing was wrong...

Ie. see this: [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYa6U/)

It works with a ' at the start and end of the number. Just wondering why 013 turns to 11. I did some googling and couldn't find anything...

Cheers

Robin

Edit:

Thanks guys. Yep understand now.

As in this case the 0 at the start has a meaning, here the recipient ID in a mailing list, I will use '013' instead of just 013, i.e. a string. I can then split the values in js as each of the 3 values represents a different id which will always be only 1 character long, i.e. 0-9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A numeric literal that starts with a `0` is treated as an octal number. So 13 from base 8 is 11 in base 10...

Octal numeric literals have been deprecated, but still work if you are not in strict mode.

(You didn't ask, but) A numeric literal that starts with `0x` is treated as hexadecimal.

More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Integers).

In your demo the parameter is called `id`, which implies you don't need to do numerical operations on it - if so, just put it in quotes and use it as a string.

If you need to be able to pass a leading zero but still have the number treated as base 10 to do numerical operations on it you can enclose it in quotes to pass it as a string and then convert the string to a number in a way that forces base 10, e.g.:

```
something('013');

function something(id){    
    alert(+id);             // use unary plus operator to convert
    // OR
    alert(parseInt(id,10)); // use parseInt() to convert        
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XYa6U/5/

Comment: Javascript doesn't treat '08' as octal in general, only `parseInt` does. Other methods of converting a string to number are fine, e.g. `Number('08')`, `+('08')`, `1*'08'` all return `8`, whereas `parseInt('08')` returns `0`. Treating the leading zero as indicating octal was optional, but most browsers seem to continue to implement it.

Comment: @RobG see my fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/Lc9ktzn1/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc9ktzn1/) parseInt parses numbers into base 10 no matter what. Also on that fiddle -- if a number has an 8 in it, it can't be interpreted as base 8 even if it starts with a 0, so javascript takes it as base 10.

Comment: @Jan—that was 2012, the spec has changed since then. While ES5 became the standard in June 2011, most browsers weren't compliant and continued their ECMA-262 ed 3 behaviour in regard to octal numbers for quite some time. However, now that ECMA-262 ed 6 is the spec, it seems modern browsers at least are conformant. But there are still a good number in use where a leading '0' means octal for parseInt. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Ahh, good to know! So you'd really have to do parseInt( str, 10 ) to make sure it's base 10, yes?

Comment: @Jan–yes. Providing a radix was *de rigueur* and probably still should be.  If you believe [*netmarketshare*](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), IE8 is still has about 20% user share.

Comment: *"parseInt parses numbers into base 10 no matter what"* - No it doesn't. Try `parseInt('0x123')`.

Answer (score 2):

`013` is octal, not decimal, it's equal 11 in decimal

Comment: so I need to always pass a number starting with 1-9 to be valid? i.e. get the number i 'wanted'?

Comment: Or you could use `parseInt(num, 10)`

Comment: yeah like @jahroy said, parseInt('013', 10) will return 13

Comment: @RobinRieger it isn't invalid because it starts with a zero, JavaScript just interprets it differently. just as `0xA === 10` because 0x[0-9a-f].. means interpret as hex.

Comment: If zero padding is important you should be working with either a _String_ or two _Numbers_ (one the value and the other the number of digits).

Answer (score 0):

You should note that `013` starts with a `0`. In Javascript, this causes the number to be considered octal. In general you'll want to use the decimal, and hexadecimal number systems. Occasionally though, octal numbers are useful, as [this question shows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569/octal-number-literals-when-why-ever)

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the first digit of a number is a zero, parseInt interprets the number as an octal.

You can specify a base of ten like this:

`parseInt(numberString, 10)`

You could also remove such zeros with a regex like this (the result will be a string):

`numberString.replace(/^0+/g, '');`

Comment: Javascript doesn't interpret the leading zero as octal, only `parseInt` does.