# What is the difference between 15 and 015?

Tags: c++, char, output

This might be appear to be a silly/trivial question at first, but when I do this:

```
char f_gear = 15;
```

I get the normal output

```
"☼"
```

but when I pad it with zeros when i declare it:

```
char f_gear = 015;
```

I get weird output makes text look garbled (in one line) and blanks the previous line. When I attempt to see the individual character itself, I get the following:

```
"  ◘◘@╧S☻ "
```

What is essentially different? Isn't 15==015?

==EDIT==
Stack Overflow changed the text when I posted the question. The output I really saw was a few blank characters.

Comment: Forgive me if it's a duplicate, I never knew numbers starting with 0 were octal.

Comment: No problem. You might find this interesting as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569/octal-number-literals-when-why-ever

Comment: @jogojapan <offtopic> how did you put the text as hyperlink in your comment?</offtopic> I can do this in answers, but in comments this technique eludes me.

Comment: @JoshPetitt In the 'possible duplicate' case above it happened automatically, because that comment is inserted whenever somebody votes to close a question as duplicate. But in the general case you can use the same Markdown syntax as in regular posts: `[anchortext](href)`, for example `[link to google](https://www.google.com/)` will produce [link to google](https://www.google.com/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, 015 refers to octal number. So, 015 in octal is equal to 13 in decimal.

So,

```
char f_gear = 015;
```

is equivalent to

```
char f_gear = 13;
```

Answer (score 7):

015 is octal notation. You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal. It is not used much.

Answer (score 3):

All number literals that start with 0 are in octal.

Answer (score 1):

Example, If We write the number "15". The compiler will recognize that as: 0000 1111 in binary.

If We write the number 015 the compiler will recognize that as octal and will see it as 0000 1101 in binary.

Answer (score 1):

char f_gear=015 is considered octal,and hence it is equivalent to char f_gear=13.
ASCII 13 is for carriage return ,which is the cause of the result.
Snippet below shows the values[image]