# javascript does not accept 0 before any number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calculator

```
var value = 05000;
var addValue = 1;
```

if I calculate  `value + addvalue`, then it's calculating wrong value

```
 var result = value + addValue;// it's return value is 20481
```

See this below image from quick watch result

[image]

But if I give the value to 5000( without 0 before the value), then it's calculate correct . Why?

Comment: 05000 is octal notation. The value in decimal is 5 x 8^3 = 5 x 512 = 2560. If you're getting 20481, then you are supplying 050000 (four trailing zeroes, not three), which is 5 x 8^4 = 5 x 4096 = 20480.

Comment: Btw, if you precede a number with `0x` or `0X`, it'll read as hexadecimal number. So both `0x10 === 16` and `0x10 === 020` will return true, unless `strict mode`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Putting `0` before a number makes it into an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number literal. It is interpreted thus in base 8.

For this reason - do not put leading zeros before numbers. It clearly [doesn't do what you intend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569/octal-number-literals-when-why-ever).

If you ran your code in [strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it?rq=1), you'd have gotten an error instead:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: But why it's return correct value if I calculate `01+1 =2`.

Comment: 01 in octal is the same as 01 in decimal

Comment: @RameshRajendran - Because 01 is octal notation for 1 x 8^0 = 1.

Comment: @RameshRajendran octal literals are a _different way to represent the same numbers_, just like _binary representaiton_ or hexadecimal. A good example of where this is useful that developers know of is _color codes_, ever wondered what `#EEFFAA` means? It's actually the literal `0xEEFFAA` which is a _number_ in _base 16_, it is readable since every _four digits_ mean something (the color strength of a different color- red greed or blue). Octal (base 8) is used for encoding _three_ bits instead of four (like hexadecimal). It's useful for permissions in linux for example.

Comment: okay, I think my question is good before I posted. now i understood . thanks

Comment: Easiest +10 ever. I wish I could've been quicker to answer this, I wanna hit 200 reps so bad

Comment: @GuiImamura if it makes you feel any better I'm capped, so I got around 15 reputation from this answer. Also reputation is pretty meaningless just make good content and nice things will happen - it was a lot easier getting +300 for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/16825593#16825593 than rounding up small answers.

Comment: I'm trying (to make good content). And will keep trying. Thanks, you're my hero --- I wanna be just like you when I grow up! (btw rep isn't so meaningless when you can't even comment on the askubuntu :P)